# woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation not executed

Tags: php, wordpress, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to set validation on "add cart" button to my woocommerce.
I use this code in functions.php, but it is not executed:

```
function test( $passed ) { 
    //exit(); //it would broke the code
    $passed = false;
    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'test', 10, 5 );
```

I try to set exit() on test() function but nothing. What can i verify?

Comment: I solve it. The problem was in custom theme that call woocommerce add_to_cart() directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the woocommerce source code you can see an example of how filters are added to `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation`: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/d7f768f77919a3f7a059d915894d0e87b2cb3ab1/includes/wc-cart-functions.php#L13-L27

I have personally added woocommerce filters inside of a child theme: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/ in the file `functions.php`, wrapped in the `<?php ... ?>` tag.

You could be running into a priority issue, see this comment for more info on how that could impact your function: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/7998/120919

Comment: I inserted "woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation" filter in functions.php of my theme. There are others filters and its work fine.
I'll try to change the priority...